# tensorflow requesting GLIBC 2.14 despite machine running 2.19

Tags: python, tensorflow, glibc

I've seen many posts about installing tensorflow without having to update GLIBC 2.12. I didn't have that constraint so I got GLIBC 2.19 on a GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1) linux cluster:

```
ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.19
```

I have a Python 3.4.5 virtual environment to which I've pip installed tensorflow 0.11.0 via:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

I do the following and observe:

```
python
import tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/share/apps/home_2/user/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/share/apps/home_2/user/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/share/apps/home_2/user/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/share/apps/home_2/user/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/share/apps/home_2/user/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `**GLIBC_2.14' not found** (required by /share/apps/home_2/user/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

My understanding is that there is backwards compatibility with the absent 2.14 so a downgrade to it doesn't seem like the next best step and would probably anger the admin. Are there better things to try?

Comment: For question related to build and installation, please file a github issue here:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new

Comment: "there is backwards compatibility" -- correct. It should have worked. What is the output from running `/lib64/libc.so.6` on the target machine (where `import tensorflow` fails)? Also `readelf -V /lib64/libc.so.6`.

Comment: `/lib64/libc.so.6`
GNU C Library stable release version 2.12, by Roland McGrath et al.

`readelf -V /lib64/libc.so.6` provides more output than room to display, but some bits I presume are relevant include:
 
`readelf: Error: '/lib64/libc.so.6readelf': No such file
File: /lib64/libc.so.6
Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 2166 entries:
Version definition section '.gnu.version_d' contains 17 entries:
Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 1 entries:`